# Magento 2 where is price.phtml?

Tags: magento2, php, price, login

I would hide the money to those who are not registered but can not find the file phtml.

Some help?

P.S. I found only price_clone.phtml but when i try to change it, nothing happens.

Comment: You are talking about /app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/product/price.phtml ?

Comment: Unfortunately no man, because i have Magento 2.0.2 and this route is valid for Magento 1.9. In my magento don't exist the folder code. Thank you for the answer. Some help?

Comment: You are talking about app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml on line 76 is the product price no?  <?php echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**it's either in**

**`app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/`**

or in

**`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/`**

depends on how you installed magento (direct download or composer project install)

You can look up which templates are used for which types and priceCodes in the Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool Class. But also the template names are pretty straight forward

the price of a simple product on the product detail page has the final_price.phtml template for example.

Answer (score 6):

There is also available another way how to get to know a template path.

These are **template path hints**.

A page with enabled template path hints will look like:
[image]

Template path hints can be enabled/disabled in Magento backend: Stores->Settings->Configuration->Advanced->Developer->Debug section