# how to customize product price display in product page magento 2

Tags: magento2, price, catalog-price-rules, product-detail-page

> hi  I want to customize the price display in product details page Magento 2
>
> [image: magento 2 product price]
>   where I can customize the codes
>
> (path)

**my goal:**

1) I want to add a label near the First price .

2) How I can display a discount in percentages (%) .

Can anyone tell me where I can do this updates ?

Magento version 2.2.6.

amount/default.phtml

```
<?php /** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount $block */ ?>

<span class="price-container <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAdjustmentCssClasses() ?>"
        <?= $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"' : '' ?>>
    <?php if ($block->getDisplayLabel()): ?>
        <span class="price-label"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayLabel() ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <p>Exclusive of Tax : </p> <span <?php if ($block->getPriceId()): ?> id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceId() ?>"<?php endif;?>
        <?= ($block->getPriceDisplayLabel()) ? 'data-label="' . $block->getPriceDisplayLabel() . $block->getPriceDisplayInclExclTaxes() . '"' : '' ?>
        data-price-amount="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayValue() ?>"
        data-price-type="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceType() ?>"
        class="price-wrapper <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceWrapperCss() ?>"
    ><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?></span>
    <?php if ($block->hasAdjustmentsHtml()): ?>
        <?= $block->getAdjustmentsHtml() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($block->getSchema()): ?>
        <meta itemprop="price" content="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayValue() ?>" />
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayCurrencyCode() ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Please refer this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100810/magento-2-where-is-price-phtml

Answer (score 3):

For the first Goal:
1) I want to add a label near the First price .
Follow this [Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222683/how-to-add-some-text-before-price-in-product-detail-page-in-magento-2?rq=1)
You need to override

> /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-box.js
>   And add your label :
>   [image]

For the second Goal :
2) How I can display a discount in percentages (%)

Override this file :

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

Your override

> app/design/frontend/Your/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

And add the below code under this section `<span class="old-price">...</span>`:

```
 <span class="price-percentage">
        <?php $percentage = 100 - round(($finalPriceModel->getAmount()->getValue() / $priceModel->getAmount()->getValue())*100); ?>
        <?php echo $percentage ."% OFF"?>
    </span>
```

Comment: i have enable two prices 
one is inclusive of tax   and exclusive of tax 

the label is showing for both price 

so, how i can only show for one price....

Comment: price-percentage  is not showing in front end..

Comment: Then open the hints where the price of exluding and including are , do a control there  `<?php if ($block->displayPriceExcludingTax()): ?>   <span class="price"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ (add your label) $block->getDisplayAmountExclTax() ?></span></span> <?php endif; ?>` , check you are doing the override ok for the price-percentage , check if the product has discount , clear cache and static files , run reindex .

Comment: showing error for  <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ (add your label) $block->getDisplayAmountExclTax() ?>  this line

error : expected ):

Comment: getDisplayAmountExclTax()  is not a method

Comment: @prabhakaran7 open the hints to find the template who displays the price and check the function , do the modfication there.

Comment: i added the code in question (plz check updated)----
 that displaying price
one tag contains two prices.....

Answer (score 0):

**Add custom text under price details on product page Magento 2**

Hello guys, too often we need to add some custom text under the price details on the product view page. Here is how we can do it without many efforts.

***NOTE - IT WILL CHANGE THE PRICE BOX FOR THE WHOLE WEBSITE.***

**The first step is to overwrite the pricing renderer-**

for this, you can add the following code in `di.xml` in the `app/code/Vishal/CustomPriceRender/etc` folder-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" type="Vishal\CustomPriceRender\Plugin\Pricing\Renderer\FinalPriceBox"/>
</config>
```

**The second step is to create the renderer file that we have defined in di.xml**

write the following code to `FinalPriceBox.php` in `app/code/Vishal/CustomPriceRender/Plugin/Pricing/Renderer` Folder –

```
<?php
namespace Vishal\CustomPriceRender\Plugin\Pricing\Renderer;

use Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox as BasePriceBox;
use Magento\Msrp\Pricing\Price\MsrpPrice;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Pricing\Renderer\SalableResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\SaleableInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\MinimalPriceCalculatorInterface;

class FinalPriceBox extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox
{
    
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        SaleableInterface $saleableItem,
        PriceInterface $price,
        RendererPool $rendererPool,
        array $data = [],
        SalableResolverInterface $salableResolver = null,
        MinimalPriceCalculatorInterface $minimalPriceCalculator = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $saleableItem, $price, $rendererPool, $data);
        $this->_registry = $registry;
    }
    
    public function wrapResult($html)
    {
        return '<div class="price-box '.$this->getData('css_classes').'" '.'data-role="priceBox" '.'data-product-id="'.$this->getSaleableItem()->getId().'"'.'>'.$html.'(Price/Kilometer)</div>';
    }
}
```

**see the below screenshot for result -**

[image]